# como actualizar la página cada cierto tiempo y cambien los iconos de los marcadores del mapa?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una pagina donde tengo establecidos unos marcadores con iconos de color verde(los marcadores están en un archivo json), y necesito hacer que cada cierto tiempo, por ejemplo 2 minutos, esos iconos verdes cambien a otros iconos con otro color que tengo descargados, así constantemente. como puedo hacerlo? mostrare parte del codigo y como se ven actualmente los marcadores, de antemano muchas gracias.

```js
 var rIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'marcadores/marker-icon-green.png',
    })
  
    for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; ++i ) 
       {      
       L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: rIcon} )
       .bindPopup( '<a href="' + markers[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + markers[i].name + '</a>' ).addTo( cities );
       }
```

json:

```
      markers = [
  {
     "name": "Puente Alto",
     "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puente_Alto",
     "lat": -33.595775,
     "lng": -70.575753


   },

   {
     "name": "Las Condes",
     "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Condes",
     "lat": -33.420391,
     "lng": -70.550346

   },

   {
     "name": "Santiago",
     "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_(comuna)",
     "lat": -33.463083,
     "lng": -70.673822
   },

   {
     "name": "Inspector 1",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.441520,
     "lng": -70.738274
   },

   {
     "name": "Inspector 2",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.527853,
     "lng": -70.648154
   },

   {
     "name": "Vehículo Detenido",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.431848,
     "lng": -70.607229
   },

   {
     "name": "Carabineros de Chile",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.504342,
     "lng": -70.683327
   }


];
```

y asi se ve actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Como los iconos los cargas desde un json podrias usar algunas cosas de ES6 para almacenarlos de manera sencilla en una variable, en el código, luego, si los deseas mostrar en un orden en especifico, crear un iterador que contendrá la posición actual de las referencias de las url de los iconos y el nombre que le colocaras al link. Luego usar la función setInterval de javascript y configurarla en tu caso me haz dicho que 2 minutos cuando la pagina se halla cargado, así que yo haría algo como esto:

**Primer paso:** crear la variable que almacenara este JSON y crear el iterador numérico, tambien obtener el elemento en javascript al cual le modificaremos su contenido dinamicamente cada cierto tiempo:

```
const miMarcador = document.getElementById("miMarcador");
let miJSON;
let i = 0;
```

**Segundo paso:** crear la función que me permita cargar mi JSON en mi archivo script principal.

```
function loadAJSON(ruta){

     return fetch(`${ruta}`).then(j => j.json());

}
```

**Tercer paso:** lo siguiente sería crear la función que nos permitirá cambiar el icono cada cierto tiempo, cabe destacar que es buena idea crear un arreglo de rutas para poder usar la variable numérica que anteriormente habíamos creado como iterador, tambien uno de nombres:

```
function cambiarIcono(data){

        let arregloRutas = [];
        let arregloNombres = [];

        data.forEach((elem)=>{

              arregloRutas.push(elem.url);
              arregloNombres.push(elem.name);

        })

        /*No estoy seguro de lo que haces en tu código con la función 
 bindPopUp en el código (Nunca la había visto) lo único que se es que el 
 valor que debes poner en el href es arregloRutas[i]*/

        miMarcador.href = arregloRutas[i];
        miMarcador.innerText = arregloNombres[i];

        //Y luego cambiamos el valor de nuestro iterador:
        i = i < arregloRutas.length - 1 ? i + 1 : 0;

    }
```

**Por ultimo:**

Le añades a la función cambiarIcono un setInterval, (el valor numérico que vez de la función son los milisegundos que va a tardar la función en volver a ejecutarse).

```
miJSON = loadAJSON("mijson.json")
.then((data)=>{

      cambiarIcono(data);

});

setInterval(()=>{

    miJSON.then((data)=>{

        cambiarIcono(data);

    });

}, 120000);
```

120000 milisegundos equivalen a 2 minutos, por lo tanto la función se ejecutara cada 2 minutos y cambiara el icono, lo de miJSON.then(), se trata de una función especial que utilizan las promises y que permite obtener el valor de una promise, (Código asincrono), entonces obtenemos la data de la promise con .then() (En caso de que se halla resuelto correctamente la promise) y la enviamos como parámetro a la función cambiarIcono.

por cierto, tenias un error en el JSON, tuve que cambiar tu JSON a esto:

```
 [
  {
     "name": "Puente Alto",
     "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puente_Alto",
     "lat": -33.595775,
     "lng": -70.575753


   },

   {
     "name": "Las Condes",
     "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Condes",
     "lat": -33.420391,
     "lng": -70.550346

   },

   {
     "name": "Santiago",
     "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_(comuna)",
     "lat": -33.463083,
     "lng": -70.673822
   },

   {
     "name": "Inspector 1",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.441520,
     "lng": -70.738274
   },

   {
     "name": "Inspector 2",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.527853,
     "lng": -70.648154
   },

   {
     "name": "Vehículo Detenido",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.431848,
     "lng": -70.607229
   },

   {
     "name": "Carabineros de Chile",
     "url": "https://www.fiscalizacion.cl/",
     "lat": -33.504342,
     "lng": -70.683327
   }

]
```

Ah, con respecto a recargar la pagina cada cierto tiempo, no es necesario para que los marcadores cambien, pero si requieres hacerlo de todas maneras, existe la función location.reload().